# I can't get my pictures to render on HTML

Tags: html, image, rendering

I can't get my pictures to render in HTML. You can see my source code in the screen shot and the seven pictures that are not rendering on my localhost. Where am I going wrong on such a simple piece of code? I mean I could render a picture from the net, no problem but I can't render one off a directory in my own machine?!? Your help is much appreciated.

[image: The source code and directory]

[image: How the code renders on the screen]

Comment: Try adding a forward slash before /public/.  Some more details about your environment might also help others diagnose your issue. WAMP?

Comment: Thanks but that didn't change anything. I'm using Meteor 0.9.1.1 and PHPStorm on a Mac OSX. No major modifications to the Meteor/WebStorm applications. This picture is from the Chrome browser but it shows the same thing in Safari only the sky is a "?".

Comment: I'd guess it's the image path. When you switch the image with one from the internet (at the same path), it suddenly works? Try right clicking the image and selecting "Copy image URL". What does it show you?

Comment: I gave up trying to put them on my local machine and put them on a private web based URL and copied the image path.